# Data bind element name of another control inside datatemplate of a datagridtemplatecolumn, and the converter is not firing

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

```
<UserControl.Resources>

            <local:ColorConverter x:Key="cc"></local:ColorConverter>

</UserControl.Resources>
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="gridAllContacts"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="500"                   Height="300"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">

      <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="{Binding ElementName=columns2, Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource cc}}" ></TextBox>
                   </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
           </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
     </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>              

 </sdk:DataGrid>
 <ComboBox Name="columns2"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,0,0,0" SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBoxItem>Name</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>School</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>ContactID</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

The background of the textbox inside datatemplate for a specific column should be colored according to the ComboBox item selected. But right now the converter is not firing at all when I put a break point inside my converter class. I read somewhere that you need a DataContextProxy, if so how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and move the combo box into the UserControl's resources (change the name to x:Key).

Then replace the original combo box location with a ContentPresenter whose content is the combo box in the resources.

The datagrid's binding needs to be altered to Background="{Binding Source={StaticResource comboBoxKeyInResources}", Path=SelectedIndex...

This way the converter binding should work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it right by doing this which works exactly the way I wanted:

```
        DataGridCell tempCell = new DataGridCell();

        Style cellStyle = new Style();
        cellStyle.TargetType = tempCell.GetType();
        cellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));
        gridAllContacts.Columns[0].CellStyle = cellStyle;
```